# 20599 cannot open sql vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms, crystal-reports

i am creating a winform app in which i want to see the reports for which i am using crystal report 8

i am creating this winform app in vs2003 and using sql server 2008

all is working fine until i tried to view my reports in which i am getting the error [here is my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QWTg.jpg)

this is how i provide my connection

```
        objCR.LogonInfo(0) = "server=" & Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Item("SERVER") & _
        " ; database=" & Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Item("DATABASE") & _
        "; uid = " & Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Item("UID") & _
        "; pwd = " & Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Item("PWD")
```

this is my app.config

```
<add key="UID" value="username" />
<add key="PWD" value="password" />
<add key="SERVER" value="sql" />
<add key="DATABASE" value="database" />
```

what is wrong in this code?

Comment: There is no end quote in this line `<add key="SERVER" value="sql />`

Comment: Why not use the `<ConnectionStrings>` section?  It is designed for your connection strings and eliminates the need for all this error prone string concatenation.

Comment: project is running with connectionstring but crystal report is not able to open sql connection @ChrisDunaway how to pass connection string to crystal report